# 'mvn clean install': why does 'clean' run after 'install'?

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, maven-install-plugin, maven-clean-plugin

If I run 
`mvn clean install` why does maven do the clean after the install?

The reason I ask is because I want to grab the generated EAR from the workspace and not the repo location after jenkins has called maven

Here's a section of the console output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ myProject.EAR ---
[INFO] Installing target/myProject.EAR-1.0.0.ear to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/uk/co/mycompany/myProject.EAR/1.0.0/myProject.EAR-1.0.0.ear
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MP/workspace/myProject.EAR/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/uk/co/mycompany/myProject.EAR/1.0.0/myProject.EAR-1.0.0.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 20.5.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myProject ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MP/workspace/myProject/target
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `mvn clean install` , it executes for each module, that is parent project and each submodule. Your log excerpt shows that it finished the `install` part for `myProject.EAR` project, and started working on the `myProject`, starting with `clean` as it prints `(default-clean) @ myProject` .

This is also evident from the paths in the log: The first module is located at `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MP/workspace/myProject.EAR`, while the second module is located at `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MP/workspace/myProject` .

Perhaps you could describe what you're doing and what doesn't work, but this part of the build seems to work as designed .

Comment: Ah, yes. That explains it. I'm thinking of it as one build, but there's multiple modules. In this case, a parent, an EAR, and 4-5 WARs.